# Capturar digito entre parênteses

Tags: regex

Tenho diversos tipos de textos, como por exemplo: `$ticker="08.070.838/0001-63.offset(1)"`.

Quero capturar o texto e o dígito, se houver, que está entre parênteses para transformá-lo na forma `"08.070.838/0001-63.offset+1"`.

Estou tentando pelo regex `'(\S*)\((\d)\)'` utilizado no php pelo `preg_match` da seguinte forma:

```
if(preg_match('(\S*)\((\d)\)', $ticker, $match)) $ticker=$match[0]."+".$match[1];;
```

Porém está retornando a mensagem de erro:

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\'.

Alguém saberia o que está errado em alguma dessas `\`?

Comment: Qual linguagem esta usando?

Comment: Estou tentando utilizar expressões regulares pelo PHP

Comment: `Matcher textoParenteses = Pattern.compile("(.)").matcher(textoOrignal)` 
 `String textNovo = textoParenteses.replace('(','+').replace(')','')` Isso em Java no caso, acredito que de para adaptar para PHP

Comment: Tente `$res = preg_replace('\((?=\w*\d*\))', '', $ticker);` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eWCTZv/2) e `$res = preg_replace('\)(?=$)', '+', $ticker);` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eWCTZv/1) para substituir os parenteses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quero capturar o texto e o dígito (se houver) que está entre parênteses

Tente essa regex: `(".*?)\((\d*?)\)`

> [...] para transformá-lo na forma "08.070.838/0001-63.offset+1".

Para fazer essa transformação você deve usar o método `preg_replace` dessa forma:

```
<?php
$string = '08.070.838/0001-63.offset(1)';
$pattern = '/(".*?)\((\d*?)\)/g';
$replacement = '$1+$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/yrKA1E/1).

**Explicação:**

Pattern de captura:
 - `(.*?)\(` - Captura todo o texto até o `(`.
 - `(\d*?)\)` - Captura todos os dígitos depois do `(` até o `)`.

Replacement:
 - `$1+` - Reproduz o que está capturado no grupo 1 com um símbolo de + após o conteúdo. 
 - `$2` - Reproduz o que está capturado no grupo 2.

> Alguém saberia o que está errado em alguma dessas \?

Você não está usando `delimiters` na sua expressão, está colocando ela crua, você sempre deve começar com o `delimiter` "/" para iniciar o padrão e se quiser encerrar com o `modifier` que deseja.

Você pode encontrar a documentação sobre `delimiters` [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)